# How to store array in usermeta in wordpress

Tags: posts, user-meta

I have a custom user registration form and am trying to store multiple values in the usermeta. This is a sample code I am using, however it just stores the last option selected (i.e. if I select from Volvo to Opel, it will only store Opel in the database), whereas what I am wanting is all the values selected to be stored. Im not sure what Im doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<select name="test" id="test" multiple>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    update_usermeta( $new_user, 'test', $_POST['test'] );
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100023/settings-api-with-arrays-example/100137#100137) for how to store array data. It is using `update_option()`, but that works the same way as `update_user_meta()`.

Answer (score 1):

Subtle difference in your `name` declaration, which needs to be `name="test[]"`.

```
<select name="test[]" id="test" multiple>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

    update_usermeta( $new_user, 'test', $_POST['test'] );
```

Edit re: your comment,

```
$meta = get_user_meta($user_id, 'test'); 
foreach ($meta as $key => $value) { 
    echo $value; 
}
```

Comment: This was correct, however how do I print the array so it shows the values.  At present it displays like this in the user profile Array ( [test] => Array ( [0] => volvo [1] => saab [2] => opel [3] => audi ) )

Comment: Thank you - that didn't work but I tried this '$meta = get_the_author_meta( 'test', $user->ID, true ); 
foreach($meta['test'] as $meta) {
    echo $meta['test'], '<br>';
}' and it now shows up the values, but only the first letter?

Comment: $user_id is a placeholder for $user->ID, you need to make sure you pass the actual ID of the user to the function. Hard to tell without seeing your full code. Your foreach function is also incorrect.

Comment: [update_usermeta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_usermeta) is deprecated as of Version 3.0. Please use [update_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) instead