# register_setting - validation callback weirdness

Tags: plugins, validation

I'm working on a plugin and having some issues validating input on its settings page. I'll try to explain as briefly as possible what I'm doing in the plugin file:

```
if (is_admin()) {
    add_action('admin_init', 'register_mysettings');
    add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu');
}

function t1k_twitter_menu() {
    add_options_page('My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my_plugin', 'my_plugin_options');
}

function t1k_twitter_options() {
    // include my form
    include 'my_plugin_options.php';
}

function register_mysettings() { // whitelist options
    register_setting('my-group', 'setting_1', array($this, 'validate'));
    register_setting('my-group', 'setting_2', array($this, 'validate'));
}

function validate($input) {
    // This is where I want to do some validation...
}
```

From various examples I've seen, it seems that I should be receiving a key-value array as $input in the validate function. What I actually see is a simple string containing the posted value.

Have I misunderstood, or is my implementation wrong? The options will save ok (if I remove my validate function, or just set it to return the posted value).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100137/73)? Also, there is a typo in your code.

Comment: Please post your **actual validation function code**, rather than `// This is where I want to do some validation...`; otherwise, it will be impossible to answer your question. (Also, fix the syntax error on the `add_options_page()` line.)

Comment: toscho, I had not seen that answer, thanks - that could help, I will give it a try. For reference, is that documented somewhere in the WordPress docs?

Comment: Chip, there is no validation code - the value of $input is only ever the string entered in the form field (with no way of identifying the field) so I haven't written any yet.

Comment: Well, if you define a validation callback, and pass it `$input`, but don't *return* `$input`, then the Settings API won't ever be able to save your settings to the database.

Comment: Chip, "The options will save ok (if I remove my validate function, or just set it to return the posted value)" - what I'm saying is, looking at the docs it appears that $input should be an key/value array, all I'm seeing is a value though (so can't tell what field it's coming from).