# Serialize data for wp options

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, options, plugin-options

I am creating my first ever plugin, its purpose is to show a notice when some conditions are met, I created the function in jQuery and initially I had to manually edit the file everytime I wanted to change the notice message, so I decided to create a settings page so that the user could edit the message from the front end.

Thanks to another member on stackxchange I was able to use wp localize to show the custom message saved in the wp options instead. however, I now find my self having to structure the message being shown such as;

```
Title

Message

Image
```

I don't want to create many options so I thought I could try and serialize the data but I dont know how to.

In the settings page I have a single textbox for the user to enter the message.

```
<textarea name="msg_data" id="msg_data" cols="40" rows="10" />
<?php echo get_option('notice_data'); ?>
</textarea>
```

Here is the localize

```
$custom_notice = get_option('notice_data', 'default_value');
  wp_localize_script( 'lu_ban', 'custom_notice', $custom_notice);
```

My goal is to create three different inputs, one for title, one for body message and one for image path, can anyone help me out please.

THanks

Comment: Like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100137/73)?

Answer (score 2):

To store Data use this Code : save the serialize values

```
$title    = 'Your Title Value';
$message  = 'Your message HTML..';
$image    = 'http://www.domain.com/yourimage.jpg';

$notice_data = array('title'   => $title, 
                     'message' => $message,
                     'image'   => $image
                    );


if(get_option('notice_data') === FALSE){
    add_option('notice_data',  $notice_data );
}else{
    update_option('notice_data', $notice_data );
}
```

Now you can get the serialize values and use in your code

```
$notice_data =   get_option('notice_data')  ;  

echo $notice_data['title'];

var_dump($notice_data);
```

Comment: add/update option serializes data automatically, all you need to do is pass an array. using serialize/unserialize here is redundant.

Comment: Yes that's TRUE.

Comment: @ShahinulIslam please update you answer, remove serialize/unserialize

Comment: My serialized data looks like `a:2:{s:5:"Title";s:11:"custom message";s:7:"Message";s:20:"Hello testing testing";}` how do I now return it to a form, I tried `<?php echo get_option('notice_data[Title]'); ?>` but it doesnt work

Comment: Jose David Garcia Llanos   - you can unserialize($notice_data) to make that serialize data into array. I update the answer.