# Run function AFTER theme options are saved?

Tags: settings-api, customization

Weird question, how can I run a custom function AFTER my theme settings are saved? I see that the register_settings() function has a sanitize callback, but that runs before the settings are changed. I need something to run after they're saved. Is there an action or filter I can use to do that?

EDIT -

SO I have this setting I made:

```
add_settings_section(
    'kjd_body_background_settings_section', // ID hook name
    null, // label
    null, // function name
    'kjd_body_background_settings' // page name
);


    add_settings_field(
        'kjd_body_background_colors', // ID hook name
        null, //label
        null, //callback
        'kjd_body_background_settings', // page name
        'kjd_body_background_settings_section' // parent section 
);
```

and this function:

```
function kjd_update_stylesheet( $oldvalue, $_newvalue ){
   echo 'updated!';
   die();
}
add_action('update_options_kjd_body_background_settings','kjd_update_stylesheet',10, 2);

//add_action('update_options_kjd_body_background_colors','kjd_update_stylesheet',10, 2);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the filter `update_option_{$option}`. It runs after a successful saving.

`$option` is the name of your option, and you get the old and the new value as parameters.

From `wp-includes/option.php`:

```
do_action( "update_option_{$option}", $oldvalue, $_newvalue );
```

Use it like this for an option `wpse_themesettings`:

```
add_action( 'update_option_wpse_themesettings', 'wpse_check_settings', 10, 2 );

function wpse_check_settings( $old_value, $new_value )
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Hmmm ok. So if I have dozens of options, over dozens of pages/options groups I would have to make a hidden option for each page to run the same function?

Comment: No, you just use the names of the options you want to save. No extra hidden options.

Comment: yeah I thought of that on my way into work and said "duh"! Thanks for the answer though, you just made my project 100% more awesome

Comment: Hey, just so we are clear. When you say to use update_option{$option} you mean the $page argument in the register_settings() function right? so like

`add_settings_field( $id, $title, $callback, $page, $section, $args );`

Or is it the ID name?

Comment: Also - I just tried both and they didnt seem to fire the custom. See my updated question for the code I used

Comment: No, it is the first argument in `register_setting()`. See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100137/73) for details.

Comment: OMG such an annoyance