# How to insert multiple checkbox values into post as custom fields from frontend

Tags: custom-field, forms, front-end

I need to use a form in the front-end that allows people to post. I have tried to keep the minimum code in order to focus only on the issue (mentioned below) at hand.

**EXAMPLE FORM**:

```
    <form method="POST" id="test_form" name="test_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">

          <div>LOCATION : <input type="text" name="location" id="location"/></div>           

    <div>CHECKBOXES : 
         <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="orange"/>Orange</br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="apple"/>apple</br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="banana"/>banana
     </div>

 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="post_action" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="PROCEED"/>
```

**EXAMPLE PROCESSING** :

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] &&  !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == "post_action") {

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $error = "";

        if ($_POST['location'] != null) {
        $location = trim(strip_tags($_POST['location']));
        } else {
        $error .= 'Put location.</br>';
        }           
    } 

            $fruits= $_POST['fruits'];

        if (empty($error)) {   
        $new_post = array(   //insert form inputs, set var and define array
        'post_title'    =>  $location, 
        'post_content'  =>  $description,
        'post_status'   =>  'draft',
        'post_author'   =>  '2',
        'fruits'        => $fruits,
        'post_type'     => 'post'  
        // assigning tags and categories are no issue
        );

        $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    //ADD OUR CUSTOM FIELDS 
    add_post_meta($pid, 'fruits', $fruits, false);                          

    } 
}
```

**THINGS TRIED** : I have searched a lot on net, results were either overly complex or too project-specific. Also most of the results in this forum search came out related either to custom-post-types, custom fields or meta-boxes only. I now have a partial solution though. I have followed this [tutorial](http://voodoopress.com/expanding-our-front-end-post-meta-boxes-with-dropdowns-radio-selection-and-checkboxes/) and was able to get a single custom-field key-value pair in my post by using `add_post_meta($pid, 'fruits', $fruits, false);`.

**ISSUE** : So basically what I am looking is to get **all the values** of the checkboxes, *whichever is ticked*. I shall greatly appreciate any solution suggested in an uncomplicated manner. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple selections to work the `name` attribute of your form has to be an array, you can specify that like this: `name="fruits[]"` - or as complete line:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruits" id="fruits[]" value="apple" />
```

This is well documented, for example:

- [Settings API with arrays example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100023/settings-api-with-arrays-example)
- [HTML input array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688880/html-element-array-name-something-or-name-something)

Comment: thanks, I have gone through the resources pointed out but still am cluless on how do I insert selected multiple values in wordpress

Comment: The fruits variable is an array of the selected values now and will be saved into post meta as serialized string - take a look at: [add_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta)

Comment: Please note that I have updated my form inputs. Secondly my rest of the code should work now then. right? Because I am getting all the values into the created posts except the checkbox values.

Comment: I just saw that the `value` attribute on your `type="hidden"` input doesn't match the `name` attribute of your form. You might want to change that.

Comment: pl ignore that part as the snippet put here is extremely trimmed part of a fairly complex multi part form with sessions previews and what not. Trust me, Everything else works as expected.

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($_POST['fruits']);` and is it an array?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10977/discussion-between-gurung-and-ialocin)