# Plugin development: can't update settings with multiple settings sections

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I've got my plugin options set up to be in multiple sections, for ease of use and more efficient database calls. However, since reorganizing my Options page I can only seem so save changes made in the last section. No changes I make to earlier sections take effect.

The code for the admin options page is here: https://github.com/cconover/wp-author-customization/blob/master/author-customization/admin/author-customization-admin.php

Here's a screenshot of the Options page:
[image]

I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face, but I need some help looking in the right place.

Comment: Try dividing them into tabs. Can't remember where I've seen this. But remembered the a tutsplus tutorial on Settings API shed some light on it - to save their data, dividing them into tabs works.

Comment: Have you read [Settings API with arrays example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100023/settings-api-with-arrays-example/100137#100137)?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I needed to have a single value for `$option_group` across all `register_settings` and `settings_fields`. It's working now.

Comment: Woken from dead, but really helpful.