# Custom options - register, defaults and delete empty fields (Settings API)

Tags: customization, options, settings-api, user-registration

I cant figure out how to register all of my setting fields into 1 database option.

Code for my menu page:

```
add_menu_page('Custom options', 'Custom Options', 'manage_options', 'rm_options', 'display_options_page');
```

then my main function to add and register section, fields etc.

```
function rm_register_custom_settings_fields() {
    add_settings_section('rm_contact_info', 'Contact Info', 'rm_contact_info_callback', 'rm_options');

    add_settings_field('rm_number', 'Number:', 'rm_input_fields_callback', 'rm_options', 'rm_contact_info', array('rm_number', 'Description'));
    add_settings_field('rm_adress', 'Adress:', 'rm_input_fields_callback', 'rm_options', 'rm_contact_info', array('rm_adress', 'Description'));
    add_settings_field('rm_about_us', 'About us:', 'rm_textarea_fields_callback', 'rm_options', 'rm_contact_info', array('rm_about_us', 'Description'));

    register_setting('rm_options_group', 'rm_number', 'esc_attr');
    register_setting('rm_options_group', 'rm_adress', 'esc_attr');
    register_setting('rm_options_group', 'rm_about_us', 'esc_attr');
}
```

then im displaying the options like this:

```
function rm_display_options_page() { ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2><?php echo 'Custom options for:' . wp_get_theme(); ?></h2>
        <div class="description">Description</div>

        <?php settings_errors(); ?>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                settings_fields('rm_options_group');
                do_settings_sections('rm_options');

                submit_button();
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
```

What I want to do, instead of having 3 different options in the database and registering them separately, as it is now, I want to have them saved as an array, I tried doing something like:

```
register_setting('rm_options', 'rm_options', 'esc_attr');
```

but nothing worked, how can I do this? Basically instead of:

```
echo get_option('rm_number');
```

It will be:

```
$options = get_option('rm_options');
echo $options['rm_number'];
```

And also, how can I set defaults for the get_option? If the value is empty, I want to echo some default message. It should work with `get_option('rm_options', 'default');` but I noticed that even when the fields are empty, they are saved in the database, so this default will never work. How to make this work?

And last thing, to get the default thing to work and to clean database, how can I delete options when there is nothing entered in the field? How to control this, when wordpress is updating and doing all the work by itself?

I will be really grateful when someone can help me with this, please. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you seen [Settings API with arrays example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100023/settings-api-with-arrays-example)?

Comment: @toscho I just checked it and its over my head. Sorry, Im trying to understand it but i just need to know, how to make this works. There is just too much going on and its confusing me, any simpler example?

Comment: If you need it simple, stop using the so called _Settings API_.

Comment: @toscho then what am I supposted to use? I just want to create few options, I dont think wordpress offers any other way to create custom options. Any way you can help me?

Comment: Use `admin-post.php`. [Example](https://github.com/toscho/t5-ajax-editor)

Comment: @toscho But thats even more code that I currently have, and I understand this code at least a little bit. I just want to modify my code to use array instead of separate values, but I dont know how to modify the register_setting function, and then add the defaults. And also if possible to delete empty fields from the db, thats all.