# When using an options array the Settings API isn't creating the database record

Tags: plugin-development, array, settings-api

At the moment i am building my first plugin. So far i've saved as well as successfully uninstalled the options with single db records; everything worked like a charm. At the moment i try to improve things and group all options (checkbox values) into a single array. But when i install and activate the plugin no database record is created. :/

```
function mm_install() {
    global $wp_version;
    if ( version_compare( $wp_version, '4.0', '<' ) ) {
        wp_die( __('This plugin requires WordPress version 4.0 or later', 'mmrequest' ) );
    }
    $mm_options = array(
        'title'     => 0,
        'caption'   => 0,
        'alt'       => 0,
        'desc'      => 0
    );
    if( get_option( 'mm_options_array' ) == false) {
        add_option( 'mm_options_array', $mm_options );
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'mm_install' );
```

Comment: Do not store default options in the database, only the difference to the default values.

Comment: You mean delete the `if( get_option` and the `add_option` within the brackets? And just define the array?

Comment: There is no need to store _known_ values in the database. Defaults are always available to your script. Use `wp_parse_args()` to compare them to changed values. See also [Settings API with arrays example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100137/73)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Am still a bit confused getting my head wrapped around the settings api.

Comment: You don't have to use it. I don't. :)

Comment: yep me neither now. ;) within the init the `$mm_options` as well as the if statement and the `add_option` within got removed ;))). feels lighter